# Relacionar cuatro tablas en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Intento relacionar 4 tablas asi:

tabla usuario

```
id | nombre 
-----------
 1 | pedro
 2 | miguel
```

tabla bolantecompra

```
idbolante | idusuario | propiedadid | pago
-------------------------------------------
1         | 1         | 1           | 5000
2         | 2         | 3           | 6150
```

tabla propiedad

```
idpropiedad | direccion         | barrioid
------------------------------------------
1           | calle falsa 1234  | 1
2           | otra calle 1234   | 2
3           | mitre 1234        | 3
```

tabla barrio

```
idbarrio | medidas | localidad
------------------------------
1        | 325m2   | tigre
2        | 5000m2  | san fernando
3        | 400m2   | olivos
```

Hasta ahora logre traer dos datos

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario 
    INNER JOIN bolantecompra ON bcompralote.idusuario = usuario.id 
    INNER JOIN propiedad ON propiedad.idpropiedad = bcompralote.propiedadid
    INNER JOIN propiedad ON propiedad.barrioid = barrio.idbarrio
    WHERE id = 2";
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es solo `migel 6150` y deberia ser `miguel 6150 mitre 1234 olivos`.

Bueno, espero me ayuden. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en el tercer `INNER JOIN`, en vez de propiedad debería se barrio: sustituye `INNER JOIN propiedad` por `INNER JOIN barrio` en la cuarta línea.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario 
    INNER JOIN bolantecompra ON bcompralote.idusuario = usuario.id 
    INNER JOIN propiedad ON propiedad.idpropiedad = bcompralote.propiedadid
    INNER JOIN barrio ON propiedad.barrioid = barrio.idbarrio
    WHERE id = 2";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roger, me estaba volviendo loca.